Global padding not applied to content inside full width container
I'm building my first block theme using twentytwentyfour as a starting point and guide. I've run into an issue with content width inside a full width container (group or cover block). A typical design pattern is where I use a full width group block so I can set a full width background. Although the background is full width, I want the inner content to be constrained. This works ok at wider screen widths using the settings > layout > contentSize value from theme.json as the max-width for the inner contents. But at widths less than that value, the content butts right up against the left and right edges of the screen. This is where I thought global padding (styles > spacing > padding) would solve this problem. But I've observed that this global padding is only applied when the outer block is not full width. I would have expected it to be applied to all 'content width' content.
I have come up with a css hack which applies width as a percentage to the inner contents, thereby keeping some spacing on left and right edges:
body .is-layout-constrained > :where(:not(.alignleft):not(.alignright):not(.alignfull)) { width: 90%;}

However I feel that I must be missing something and should not have to resort to a CSS hack since this is a common design pattern and should be accommodated with theme.json settings alone. Am I missing something or is this a WordPress issue?
